# Best way to Access data from two databases in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a situation in which I need to access data from two databases as follow:

TableA(ID,Name,tableB_ID,TableC_ID),TableC(ID,Name) existed in X db and  tableB(ID,Name) existed in Y database.

I am having record from tableA and i need to change the name field of TableA records with Name field of tableB.

I am replacing it by fetching the records as:

```
List<Int> IDs=new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
IQueryable<TableA> resultA=Xcontext.TableAs.where(t=>IDs.Contains(t.ID));

Dictionary<int,string> resultB = YContext.TableB.Where(t=>resultA.Select(a=>a.tableB_ID).Contains(t.ID));
```

Changing the Name field as

```
resultA.ToList().ForEach(a=>a.Name=resultB.FirstORDefault(r=>r.ID==a.tableB_ID))
```

I need resultA As queryable So that i can use Association to access data in listView as

```
<% Eval("TableC.Name")%>
```

am i following the right approch? Plz suggest me any another way which can be better if any.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a problem with fetching the `resultB` (`YContext`) because you use `Queryable` from different database context (`XContext`) :

```
resultB = YContext.TableB.Where(t=>resultA.Select(a=>a.tableB_ID).Contains(t.ID));
```

As far as I know some Linq Drivers cannot easily evaluate `IQueryable` that contains expressions from different context than itself. So in your case first you should fetch the result from the first context (`resultA`) and then pass it tho the second context:

```
List<Int> IDs=new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
IList<TableA> resultA=Xcontext.TableAs.Where(t=>IDs.Contains(t.ID)).ToList(); //here you call ToList() that fetches the records to .net collection

//also some linq drivers are unable to parse complex expressions like Select(), so its better to move the IDs to a separate collection
var tableBIDs = resultA.Select(a=>a.tableB_ID).ToList();

var resultB = YContext.TableB.Where(t=>tableBIDs.Contains(t.ID));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. My above way of changing name is woriking fine. I am looking for another optimized way if any.

Comment: Optimization depends on your goal. This can be either a shorter code or faster execution or less memory.

Comment: Are you pointing to a particular linq driver implementation? Depending on it there may be some hacks (even using native db queries).